# General solution of the matrix equation $\dot{F}(t)=L(t) F(t)$

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, integro-differential-equations

Does there exist a solution to the matrix differential equation
$$\dot{F}(t)=L(t) F(t)$$ for a general matrix $L(t)$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. I will guess. The general matrix $L(t)$ can contain any functions of $t$ as it's elements and so can $F(t)$ and the dot means element-wise derivative with respect to $t$?

Comment: Indeed. I though it was standard.

Comment: $L$ is not a matrix. It's a matrix-valued function.

Comment: Take a look at [Antsaklis & Michel](https://books.google.com/books?id=Irr0W8s4rKUC).

Comment: If F() is invertible for each t. Multiply both sides from right by its inverse. The remaining is technique. (Just integrate).

Comment: Assuming that $F(t)\in K^n$ ($K=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and that $L(t)\in M_n(K)$.If $L(t)L(t')=L(t')L(t)$ for all $t,t'$, the general solution is $\exp(M(t))v$, where $v\in K^n$ and $M$ satisfies $M'(t)=L(t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: @GreginGre Are you really, really sure?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo , yes it's a sufficient condition. If $L(u)L(t')=L(t')L(u)$, then $\int_a^t L(u)du L(t')=L(t')\int_a^t L(u)du$ and $\int_a^t L(u)du L(t)=L(t) \int_a^t L(u)du$. Then $\exp(\int_a^t L(u)du)$ is a solution.